# How should I use web components inside web components?

Tags: javascript, web-component

I'm trying to figure out how to use a web component inside another web component (both of which inherit from the same base class.

The problem seems to be in the way I'm creating the shadow dom:

```
import BaseElement from "./base.js";

class PopupHeader extends BaseElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  async render(initial = false) {
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
        <header>
          <a href="https://example.com" id="logo" target="_blank"><img src="assets/logo.svg" alt="logo" /></a>
        </header>
      `;
  }

  async connectedCallback() {
    await this.render(true);
  }
}

customElements.define("popup-header", PopupHeader);

export default PopupHeader;
```

And base.js:

```
export default class BaseElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    
    this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
  }
```

and `main-app.js`:

```
import BaseElement from "./base.js";

class EasyApplier extends BaseElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.render = this.render.bind(this);
  }

  async render(initial = false) {
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
        <div id="${this.ns}">
          <popup-header></popup-header>
          Import profiles: <input type="file" id="json-file-input" accept="application/json" />
        </div>
      `;

  }
...
}
```

The issue is the header is only shown, not the rest of the main components html.

I suspect it has to do with this.shadowRoot being overridden, is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified your code for you. Don't know why you think you needed async on render or why you sent in parameters you didn't use.

Moved `connectedCallback()` that calls `render()` into your BaseElement.

Note, snippets on Stackoverflow doesn't require exports because it's all in the same file. You still need those if each element is in it's own separate file, but I suggest just having `export class SomeElement extends AnotherElement` instead of exporting on a single row.

The problem could be that you're trying to import from a relative path `from "./base.js"` instead of an absolute path `from "/base.js"` (no dot).

```js
class BaseElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    
    this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
  }
  
  connectedCallback() {
    this.render();
  }
}

// =======================

// import BaseElement from "/base.js"; // from the root

class PopupHeader extends BaseElement {
  render() {
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
        <header>
          <a href="https://example.com" id="logo" target="_blank"><img src="assets/logo.svg" alt="logo" /></a>
        </header>
      `;
  }
}

customElements.define("popup-header", PopupHeader);

// =======================


// import BaseElement from "/base.js";                    // from root
// import PopupHeader from "/SUBFOLDER/popup-header.js";  // from root/SUBFOLDER

class EasyApplier extends BaseElement {
  render() {
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
        <div id="${this.ns}">
          <popup-header></popup-header>
          Import profiles: <input type="file" id="json-file-input" accept="application/json" />
        </div>
      `;

  }
}

customElements.define("easy-applier", EasyApplier);
```

```html
<easy-applier></easy-applier>
```

Comment: How does this fix the original issue of overwrting the previous element's render?

Comment: I get two weird scrollbars when doing this way (whcih I saw with my original code too...I can't seem to figure out why. Its a chrome extnesion popup.html

Comment: If you click on the Run code snippet button, you will see that the header isn't overwritten. They are in their own DOM trees, so they can't overwrite each other. Like I said, it's probably more likely that you haven't defined header correctly. Try do a `console.log` in each element's constructor.

Comment: Weird I don't know why yours works but mine doesn't. ANyway, THanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick glance: `${this.ns}`?? You are calling this in the `constructing` phase??

Can't it be simplified to:

```js
class BaseElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor( html ) {
    super().attachShadow({ mode: "open" }).innerHTML = html;
  }
}

customElements.define("popup-header", class extends BaseElement {
  constructor() {
    super(`<header>POPUP-HEADER</header>`);
  }
});

customElements.define("main-header", class extends BaseElement {
  constructor() {
    super(`<h1>MAIN-HEADER</h1><popup-header></popup-header>`);
  }
});
```

```html
<main-header></main-header>
```